Verify Solutions for a Differential Equation
I am trying to solve this problem:
Consider the differential equation
x′=3x+t with an initial condition  x(0)=4. Which of the following functions is a solution to this differential equation, and what are the values of the constants?
a) $x(t)=C_0 e^{3t}+C_1t+C_2$
b)$x(t)=e^{3t}+C_1t+C_2$
and I got $3C_0 e^{3t}+C_1=3C_0e^{3t}+3C_1t+3C_2+t$
for a
and $3C_0 e^{3t}+C_1=3C_0e^{3t}+3C_1t+3C_2+t$
for b
which aren't true. Is there another way to verify solutions for DEQs and how will I solve for the constants if there are 3 unknowns and only 1 function and initial condition?

Could you add some information to your question like: Where does this question come from? Is this homework? How did you get these solutions? If we don't know what you tried we don't know what's wrong and can't help. Without more information this question is unlikely to be answered.

@OP Why did you just differentiate the expression $x(t)$? What was the goal you were trying to accomplish? The challenge at this time isn't a mathematical one, it's that you don't yet have a coherent plan, so you should actually answer that question and spell out "I wanted to check this by ___ so I differentiated ___ and now I have problem because ___", that alone might be enough to help you solve this problem.

another hint, I think you differentiated that because your goal was to check if the equation $x' = 3x+t$ is true for either of them. But you got confused because neither seemed to match the equation because you forgot that you ALSO have to specifically solve for a particular $C_0, C_1, C_2$ (meaning literally find some numbers) so that the new ODE $x' = 3x+t$ is true AND $x(0)=4$. Your differentiations are certainly correct and true but they are a step 1. in a sequence of steps you need. Can you figure out what step (2) might be and if not then we'll be happy to help you.

your attempt is correct,
$3C_0e^{3t}+C_1=3C_0e^{3t}+3C_1t+3C_2+t \Rightarrow (3C_1+1)t+(3C_2-C_1)=0, \ \forall t$
Then t and 1 are linearly independent functions, imply :
$3C_1+1=0$
$3C_2-C_1=0$
Finally
$x(0)=C_0+C_2=4$
The system of three equations can be solved. Try get the constants
